# Flutter Google Sign In not returning result if onActivityResult implemented in MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I currently use google_sign_in plugin to add Google sign in option to my Flutter application.

Everything was working fine until I add `onActivityResult()` method in my Android `MainActivity` class.

After debugging native code I found that the result is captured in `onActivityResult()` method. Hence `googleSignIn.signIn()` never returns anything.

I don't think how to solve this now. As a temporary solution I'm capturing the result in `onActivityResult()` and sending it back to flutter using `MethodChannel` but this is not the right way.

So please let me know if there is a way to figure this out.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. First, does it mean that when you delete the `onActivityResult` again, is it working as expected again? If yes, I think I know the answer. Secondly, why did you add onActivityResult to your activity? Lastly, can you share some dart code instead of describing?

Comment: 1) Yes it works if I remove onActivityResult from MainActivity
2) I've implemented screen recording in my app with the help of Native code which requires onActivityResult

Comment: Okay. Could you please share the native code, so I can answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you're checking against the request code you submitted and allowing everything else to carry on as normal?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Write your code here.
    } else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```